# ForceAtlas2 server side rendering with react sigma

Tags: node.js, sigma.js

Does anyone know how to implement server side node's position rendering & so then export with ForceAtlas2 ? So my users won't need to run ForceAtlas2 by themself
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.